# Moving Taskbar from the left to the top

Tags: unity, taskbar

I'm new to Ubuntu (like today!)and I want to move the Taskbar to the top as I have always had it in Windows. I've read a lot of posts here but everyone seems to think that the Windows placing is on the bottom. It's not, it can be on all four corners of the screen! Nobody seems to want it at the top. Why?

Comment: Other desktops are more flexible. With Lubuntu you can put the "taskbar" aka panel on the top, bottom, or either side.

Comment: The MATE and Cinnamon desktop environments allow a more flexible dash or task bar placement as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it is only possible to put the launcher on the left side or on the bottom. It's a matter of a stylistic decision on behalf of the developers if I'm not mistaken.